# Why does $<filename not run the cmd from `filename` but $`<filename` and $exec<filename works?

Tags: linux, bash

```
root@raspberrypi:~# cat >test
echo succeed
root@raspberrypi:~# <test
root@raspberrypi:~# `<test`
succeed
```

i guess the reason is a missing of `enter` signal.But how to send `enter`

Comment: If `<test` ran the shell commands in `test`, then how would one be able to redirect the contents of a file into a command, as in `cat <test`?

Comment: Do you mean that “<filename” like input something "eof".not "enter"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[In Bash, and some other shells, `` `<test` `` is a shorthand for the equivalent of `` `cat test` ``](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution):

> The command substitution `$(cat file)` can be replaced by the equivalent but faster `$(< file`).

(the same is true for `` `...` ``-style command substitution).

That means that your command

```
$ `<test`
```

is the same as

```
$ `cat test`
```

- that is, insert the contents of the `test` file onto the command line in place of the command substitution expression and then, since it's then at the start of the command, *execute the result with the first word as the command name*.

---

On the other hand,

```
$ <test
```

is just an empty command with its standard input redirected from the `test` file, [in any POSIX-like shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01). It is essentially the same as `: <test`: does nothing and succeeds. That's not very useful, but it *will* raise an error if `test` doesn't exist or isn't readable.

The reverse direction, `>test`, will create or truncate `test`, and is sometimes useful.

---

The special behaviour of `` `<test` `` and `$(<test)` in Bash, zsh, ksh, etc is inconsistent with the way command substitution generally replicates the ordinary behaviour of the same command. It's a convenience and performance feature for the sake of commands like

```
printf '%s@%s\n' $(<username.txt) $(<host.txt)
```

that want to read file contents into the command line, and get to save an extra process (by not spawning `cat` and letting the shell read the file itself).

The difference isn't anything to do with <kbd>Enter</kbd> or anything else like that - it's just a special case. I wouldn't recommend using `$(<file)` to execute a file: use `.` or `source` or some similar method instead that says what you're doing (even `eval` if it really comes to it). I wouldn't even recommend using `$(<file)` *at all* unless you're really sure you're in a tight loop where spawning an extra `cat` process mattered, because it's uncommon enough that people will be confused in exactly the way you were here.

Comment: thanks for u reply.i know the correct way.i wannna know the difference between keyboard input and file input. So $<test equals type `Enter` directly?@Michael Homer